# Simple Espresso test "Looped for x iterations over 60sec" error

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I actually tried to setup some unit test with Espresso and after some hours of research the app do only the click and get focus by the EditText but after that there is nothing

```
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 1996 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .
```

i've removed all animation & SwipeRefreshLayout cause i saw there is a bug with the swiperefresh

I actually use some callback for replace the current fragment in the Activity

if someone have some tips i'm out after 4 hours of searching u_u

Thanks you :)

---

My Gradle dependencies :

```
// App dependencies
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
// Testing-only dependencies
// Force usage of support annotations in the test app, since it is internally used by the runner module.
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
```

I've added this on the defaultConfig :

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

There is my test :

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class HelloWorldEspressoTest {

    public static final String USERNAME = "do_f";

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(LoginActivity.class);

    private LoginActivity mActivity = null;

    @Before
    public void setActivity() {
        mActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void login_LoginActivity() {

        onView(withId(R.id.menu_login)).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.login_username))
                .perform(typeText(USERNAME), closeSoftKeyboard());
    }
}
```

There is my activity :

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements MenuFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private FragmentManager fm;

    public static void newActivity(Activity activity)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(Utils.SP, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (!sp.getString(Utils.TOKEN, "null").equals("null"))
        {
            MainActivity.newActivity(this);
            finish();
        }

        fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MenuFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1)
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void showLogin() {
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, LoginFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void showRegister() {
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, RegisterFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

And my LoginFragment :

```
    private static final String        TAG = "LoginFragment";

@Bind(R.id.loading_spinner)
ProgressBar loading;

@Bind(R.id.content)
LinearLayout content;

@Bind(R.id.login_username)
EditText        username;

@Bind(R.id.login_password)
EditText        password;

public LoginFragment() {

}

public static LoginFragment newInstance() {
    return new LoginFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment_login, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(saveInstanceState);
}

@OnClick(R.id.login_submit)
public void onSubmit(View v)
{
    if (username.getText().length() == 0
            || password.getText().length() == 0)
    {
        Snackbar.make(getView(), "blabla", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return ;
    }
    //hideContent();
    LoginPost p = new LoginPost(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
    Call<LoginResponse> call = RestClient.get().login(p);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            if (response.body() == null) {
                String msg = getResources().getString(R.string.login_error_bad_credentials);
                Snackbar.make(getView(), msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //showContent();
            } else {
                SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Utils.SP, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                sp.edit().putString(Utils.TOKEN, response.body().getToken()).apply();
                sp.edit().putString(Utils.USERNAME, username.getText().toString()).apply();
                MainActivity.newActivity(getActivity());
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Snackbar.make(getView(), "onFailure", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //showContent();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56198539/4797289), use animationsDisabled in gradle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution, the looped iterations was caused by this

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/ganjify"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Because i've not set the visibility to GONE when i don't use it !

```
loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I too have the same problem, I set the visibility to GONE on the load of the progressbar to check it and still get the same problem...

Comment: @DineshVG Hey, you should check if all of your animation is finish, otherwise the espresso test will looped

Comment: Same for me, set the alpha 0 instead of visibility to gone -> AppNotIdleException (it's obvious when you know it :D)

Comment: @crysxd Yeah, it's when you know where it was then you said omagad it's ****ing obvious :D

Answer (score 4):

Espresso is designed to wait until there are no pending UI animations or AsyncTasks in your application before proceeding with tests. From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource), emphasis mine:

> Espresso provides a sophisticated set of synchronization capabilities. This characteristic of the framework, however, applies only to operations that post messages on the MessageQueue, **such as a subclass of View that's drawing its contents on the screen.**

The most likely cause for the `android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException` is that there is an ongoing UI animation or AsyncTask which Espresso is waiting to finish.

For example if you have a ProgressBar element in your layout, you would need to set the visibility `loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);` because Espresso interprets the element as an ongoing UI animation and there will wait for it to go away to proceed with testing.

Comment: @ivan.panasiuk does your TimeOutTimer control anything on the UI? Does TimeOutTimer extend another class? Don't see it in the Android docs

Comment: This is such a big limitation. i have a rotating button that rotates while the user is recording a video. Espresso hangs because it is waiting for the never ending animation to finish. I'm not prepared to disable this as it defeats the purpose of automated testing. Any workaround you can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the root cause for this issue was a **MotionLayout with an infinite animation**.
If you have some **looped animation** that goes forever your app won't reach an Idle state and tests might stuck on a random ViewInteraction while some EspressoView is waiting for Idle state.